# Are two (or more) to-infinitives treated as singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, gerunds, infinitives

A friend said to me that two (or more) to-infinitives are treated as singular (whereas gerunds can be treated as plural depending on the situation). Is it true?

Or, in this example sentence, which verb should I use?

"To control the process and to make improvement (was/were) my objectives."

Comment: That's up to the speaker. If they intend the two infinitives to refer to a single event or state or phenomenon or action or whatever, they can use the singular: _To wash the car and to dry it in the shade is my objective._ Contrariwise, they can refer to two separate things, and get the plural: _To repair the steps and to paint the porch are my objectives._

Comment: 'Bacon and eggs is my favourite meal.' / 'Bacon and eggs are both to be found on aisle 17.' Logical ( / notional) agreement after a coordinate phrase allows for the more logical verb form to be selected. This extends to situations where the nominals are to-infinitive clauses. However, the second marker is often omitted with composites: _To sit and wait wasn't an option_.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> That's up to the speaker. If they intend the two infinitives to refer to a single event or state or phenomenon or action or whatever, they can use the singular: *To wash the car and to dry it in the shade is my objective.* Contrariwise, they can refer to two separate things, and get the plural: *To repair the steps and to paint the porch are my objectives.*

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> 'Bacon and eggs is my favourite meal.' / 'Bacon and eggs are both to be found on aisle 17.' Logical ( / notional) agreement after a coordinate phrase allows for the more logical verb form to be selected. This extends to situations where the nominals are to-infinitive clauses. However, the second marker is often omitted with composites: *To sit and wait wasn't an option*.