# Another tricky subject-verb agreement question (for me)

Tags: syntactic-analysis, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, gerund-phrases

I was hoping someone could break down the following sentence that I have written into its subject, verb, and predicate parts:

> This is why supporting demand-side policies **is** a less-risky proposition.

I quickly jotted this note down in a text book and, upon reading it back to myself, it felt quite awkward. From my vantage, the intent was to convey *supporting demand-side policies* as a singular idea or concept, with that intention then more or less affirmed in (what I'm assuming is) my predicate; this consisting of *a less-risky proposition*, which denotes a singular idea.

Should I have instead used the verb *are* to link the subject and predicate? If so, is it because, simply, the subject cannot be construed as anything other than compound in nature?

Comment: Nothing tricky here at all. Up to the last paragraph, your analysis is correct. Why cloud it with doubt about whether you "should have used" the plural? The subject is a gerund clause, which is automatically singular, and there is no plural morpheme in the sentence beside the one in _policies_, which is the direct object of _supporting_, and which is **not** the subject of _is a less-risky proposition_. Whence comes this doubt?

Comment: I have yet to grasp the full complement of those exacting grammatical rules which would allow for an easy analysis (and why I'm here); however, I surmise it was "policies," which I felt may have necessitated a plural interpretation of the subject. I just did not know that gerund clauses, as a rule, were to be observed as "automatically singular." Thank you for relaying that.

Comment: Any clause or phrase that is used as the subject of a clause is automatically  singular. If they're not subjects the question doesn't arise. Like I said, number agreement conveys no information and is ignored by everyone except English teachers. And there is a rule for it, but to use it you have to learn to identify the subject, and not just look for a plural noun on the horizon.

Comment: Related and possible duplicates: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/486468), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/116240), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/550861), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/520831), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/477292), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/417680), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/18818), [8](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/302588), and plenty more besides.

Answer (score 5):

May I suggest you try and make up some sentences using gerund clauses as subjects?

Here is an example:
Explaining things repeatedly **is** frustrating. For example.

Now: Explaining things repeatedly and retaining one's composure *are* true people skills (which I do not always have.) :)

A gerund clause can function as a noun, ergo, as the subject of a sentence. two of them together will require "are" instead of "is".

Playing tennis **is** not fun for everybody.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Yes, people argue that things like "running and jumping is fun" makes of running and jumping a unit. I do not ascribe to that theory. To each his own, right?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I could not find this issue in those links. Maybe I read too fast. All I can say is that I am not referring to Green eggs and ham (a single dish) //[...]"what I'm doing is talking about doing them together as a singular activity". I guess you mean a **single activity**. I really did not get into single word uses of gerunds. So, for what I said, gerunds phrases like: playing tennis or riding horses) consisting of more than a single ing word, I'm not giving faulty advice.

Comment: Running and kissing is fun. Running and kissing are fun. Running and jumping and kissing is fun. Running and jumping and kissing are fun.

Comment: @Zan700 Running and blowing kisses, perhaps. Otherwise, I don't see how you can run and kiss as a **single activity**.